# The most efficient way to check whether a specific number of rows exists from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I'm have an oracle query as below which is working well :

```
INSERT /*+APPEND*/ INTO historical
SELECT a.* FROM TEMP_DATA a WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM historical WHERE KEY=a.KEY)
```

With the query, when i run explain plan, i notice that the optimizer chooses a `HASH JOIN` plan and the cost is fairly low

However there's a new request to state how many rows that can exists in the historical table to check against the `TEMP_DATA` table, and hence the query is changed to:

```
INSERT /*+APPEND*/ INTO historical
SELECT a.* FROM TEMP_DATA a WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM historical WHERE KEY=a.KEY) < 2
```

Which means if 1 row of record exists in the historical data given the key (not primary key), the data still could be inserted.

However with this approach the query slow down a lot, with the cost more than 10 times of the original cost. I'd also noticed that the optimizer chooses a `NESTED LOOP` plan now.

Note that the historical table is a partitioned table with indexes.

Is there anyway i can optimized this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an index on `historical(key)`?

Comment: If the historical table is partitioned and has indexes, the explain plan should show the use of partition and the index scan.

Comment: Yes there are few indexes on the historical table, including the key. The partition is done using a date column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should do the same thing and should be more performant:

```
select a.* 
  from temp_data a
  left
  join(select key, count(*) cnt
         from historical
        group
           by key
      ) b
    on a.key = b.key
 where nvl(b.cnt, 0) < 2;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks. this structure provides the base for me to restructure the query and it's now more efficient!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @DirkNM's answer would be:

```
select a.*
from   temp_data a
where  not exists (select null
                   from   historical h
                   where  h.key = a.key
                   and    rownum <= 2
                   group  by h.key
                   having count(*) > 1);
```

You would have to test with your data sets to work out which is the best solution for you.

NB: I wouldn't expect the new query (whichever one you choose) to be as performant as your original query.

Comment: In the correlated sub query, there is no need to count any row past the second row found. Adding `and rownum<= 2` to the `where` clause of the query will tell Oracle to stop looking for more rows when a second row is found.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance good point! I've updated my answer to include your suggestion. Thanks *{:-)